# Cumulative Set in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of tweets and I'm looking to group the dataframe by date and generate a column that contains a cumulative list of all the unique users who have posted up to that date. None of the existing functions (e.g., cumsum) would appear to work for this. Here's a sample of the original tweet dataframe, where the index (created_at) is in datetime format:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
            screen_name 
created_at  
04-01-16    Bob 
04-01-16    Bob
04-01-16    Sally
04-01-16    Sally
04-02-16    Bob
04-02-16    Miguel
04-02-16    Tim
```

I can collapse the dataset by date and get a column with the unique users per day:

```
In [4]: df[['screen_name']].groupby(df.index.date).aggregate(lambda x: set(list(x)))

Out[4]:             from_user_screen_name
        2016-04-02  {Bob, Sally}
        2016-04-03  {Bob, Miguel, Tim}
```

So far so good. But what I'd like is to have a "cumulative set" like this:

```
Out[4]:             Cumulative_list_up_to_this_date   Cumulative_number_of_unique_users
        2016-04-02  {Bob, Sally}                      2
        2016-04-03  {Bob, Sally, Miguel, Tim}         4
```

Ultimately, what I am really interested in is the cumulative number in the last column so I can plot it. I've considered looping over dates and other things but can't seem to find a good way. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**With recent version of Pandas, this does not work anymore and results in the following error: `NotImplementedError: function is not implemented for this dtype: [how->cumsum,dtype->object]`**

You cannot add sets, but can add lists! So build a list of users, then take the cumulative sum and finally apply the set constructor to get rid of duplicates.

```
cum_names = (df['screen_name'].groupby(df.index.date)
                              .agg(lambda x: list(x))
                              .cumsum()
                              .apply(set))
# 2016-04-01                 {Bob, Sally}
# 2016-04-02    {Bob, Miguel, Tim, Sally}
# dtype: object

cum_count = cum_names.apply(len)
# 2016-04-01    2
# 2016-04-02    4
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: That is brilliant! I didn't know that the *cumsum( )* function would create a cumulative list. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This answer no longer works since the list operation in the agg results in a "ValueError: Function does not reduce". Using .apply(list) does work.

Comment: @BrianKeegan Could you provide more info on what version of pandas breaks the above approach? We may be able to update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: This is one of the best finds I have seen so far for pandas!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `accumulate` function as a parameter to `transfrom`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: [x])
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col3'].transform(accumulate)
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2          col3
0     1     1           [1]
1     1     2        [1, 2]
2     1     3     [1, 2, 3]
3     2     1           [1]
4     2     2        [1, 2]
5     2     3     [1, 2, 3]
6     2     4  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To convert `'col3'` to set use `df['col3'].apply(set)`.